# Prove that if $f$ is continuous and $f(x)=0$ for all $x<0$ then $f(0)=0$

Tags: analysis, continuity, solution-verification

> Prove that if $f$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)=0$ for all $x<0$ then $f(0)=0$.

My attempt: $f(x)=0$ for all $x<0$ can be written as for all $\varepsilon>0$ it is $f(x-\varepsilon)=0$.

Letting $x\to0^-$ both sides of the equality leads to
$$\lim_{x\to0^-} f(x-\varepsilon)=0$$
Since by hypothesis $f$ is continuous the limit on the left hand side can be evaluated by simply substituting $x=0^-$ in $f$, so we have
$$f(-\varepsilon)=0$$
Since it is true for all $\varepsilon>0$ it is true if we let $\varepsilon \to 0^+$: letting $\varepsilon \to 0^+$ we obtain, using again the continuity of $f$, the result $f(0)=0$.

Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: Looks good-----

Comment: You do not need to take any limits to prove that $f(-\epsilon)=0$ for $\epsilon>0$. It is immediate by assumption, since $-\epsilon < 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's correct, but you used continuity of $f$ twice, when you only had to use it once. We have:
\begin{align}
f(0) = \lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^-}f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^-}(0) = 0
\end{align}
First is by continuity, second is because the limit exists, third is by hypothesis, and the last is obvious.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I agree with you by the fact that I could use continuity only once: so, to understand better, my only doubt is deduce that $f(x)=0$ by the hypothesis using the information that $x \to 0^-$.
I know that by definition of continuity of $f$ as $x \to 0^-$ I have that for all $\varepsilon>0$ exists $\delta>0$ such that if $-\delta<x<0$ then $|f(x)-f(0)|<\varepsilon$, but I can't understand fully why this assure me that $x<0$.
Is that because assuming $f$ is continuous in $x=0$ assure that $-\delta<x<0$? Because I have an "if" in the definition that confuses me. Thanks.

Comment: @ZaWarudo I'm not actually sure what the confusion regarding the "if" is. What you quoted is pretty much the definition of continuity from the left. Could you clarify the doubt/rephrase your question? Are you perhaps looking for an $\epsilon,\delta$ proof of your claim?

Comment: In the third step we want to use the hypothesis "$f(x)=0$ for $x<0$", for using it we need an information about the sign of $x$, and it seems like that this information is deduced by the fact that $x \to 0^-$.
Despite is intuitively obvious to me that "$x \to 0^-$" means that $x<0$ (at least "sooner or later" in a limit sense), it's not obvious to me how we can deduce it formally; the only thing that seems to quantify if $x$ is negative is the condition $-\delta<x<0$ in the continuity definition, but the definition contains an "if $-\delta<x<0$". How do I know if that is satisfied? Thanks.

Comment: @ZaWarudo You know the condition is satisfied because we chose to impose the condition "by hand". i.e we only consider negative values of $x$. Note that we know $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = f(0)$. What this means is regardless of how $x$ "approaches" $0$, the limiting value for $f(x)$ is $f(0)$. If we like, we can let $x$ approach $0$ through positive values, or we can allow for it to alternate sign, like $x_n = \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}$, or we can simply choose $x$ to always be negative. We may as well choose $x$ to be negative (1) because why not? and (2) because it solves the problem.

Comment: Anyway, here's an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof: let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Since $f$ is continuous at $0$, by definition, we know there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$, if $|x-0| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - f(0)| <\epsilon$. Notice that this inequality is true for all $x$ satisfying $|x| < \delta$. In particular, it will be true if we CHOOSE $x = -\frac{\delta}{2} < 0$ (this is what I meant in my previous comment about choosing $x$ to be negative). So, $|f(-\delta/2) - f(0)| < \epsilon$. But notice that $f(-\delta/2) = 0$ (by hypothesis). So, $|f(0)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Now, let's recap: one of the things we showed is that for every $\epsilon > 0$, we have $|f(0)| < \epsilon$. Hence, it follows that $f(0) = 0$, as desired (the only non-negative number which is strictly smaller than every positive number is $0$).

Comment: Thanks, it is all clearer now, you are very kind for taking time to answer me!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the work twice, i.e., you consider $x\to 0^-$ and in a second step $\epsilon\to 0^+$. One of these suffices.

So what you basically  use is that if $x_n$ is a convergent sequence in the domain of $f$, then by continuity
$$f(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n). $$
Why not use this directly with $x_n=-\frac1n$?
$$f(0)=f(\lim_{n\to\infty}-\tfrac1n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(-\tfrac 1n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}0=0. $$

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing:

Since f is continuos at 0:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{-}}f(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}=$

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x).$

For any sequence $x_n <0$, with

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n=0$ we have $f(x_n)=0.$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(x_n)=0$, and we are done.